# How to get first key of array in output in return?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a array like

```
$array = array("home" => array("dimensional" => array("array" => "data")));
```

and in `return $array;`

I am getting output like this

```
[
    {
        "dimensional": {
            "array": "data"
        }
    }
]
```

But i want first key in the output of `return();`

```
[
     "home":{
         { 
            "dimensional": {
                "array": "data"
            }
         }
     }
]
```

**How can i achieve this ?**

**code**

```
public function homepagemobile()
{
    $array = array("home" => array("dimensional" => array("array" => "data")));
    return $array;
}
```

Comment: you are returning `return $array['home']` change it to `return $array`

Comment: you can use `echo key($array);`

Comment: @C2486 i am returning return $array;

Comment: also share code where you print this  ?

Comment: create alive demo [like this](https://eval.in/1043833)

Answer (score 2):

just like this:

> $array = array("home" => array("dimensional" => array("array" => "data")));
>
> var_dump(array_keys($array)[0]);die;

Answer (score 1):

you need only return json encode

```
 return json_encode($array)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is some pattern when we `print_r()` the array:

```
$array = array("home" => array("dimensional" => array("array" => "data")));
echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);

// Output
Array
(
    [home] => Array
        (
            [dimensional] => Array
                (
                    [array] => data
                )
        )
)

print_r(json_encode($array));
// Output:
{"home":{"dimensional":{"array":"data"}}}

$array = array(array("home" => array(array("dimensional" => array("array" => "data")))));
echo '<pre>';
print_r(json_encode($array));
// Output
[{"home":[{"dimensional":{"array":"data"}}]}]
```

I think you are trying to get the last output.